# Navigational DTO properties using Entity Framework with OData Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

Development environment

- ASP.NET Core 3.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.5.1

Models

```
public class Computer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Disk> Disks { get; set; }
}

public class Disk
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public float Capacity { get; set; }
    
    public int? ComputerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Computer Computer { get; set; }
}
```

Dtos

```
public class ComputerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DiskDto> Disks { get; set; }
}

public class DiskDto
{
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public float Capacity { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core Context

```
public class ComputerContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Disk> Disks { get; set;}
    
    public ComputerContext(DbContextOptions<ComputerContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        
    }   
}
```

OData EDM Model

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    
    builder.EntitySet<Computer>("Computers");   
    builder.EntitySet<Disk>("Disks");
        
    builder.ComplexType<ComputerDto>();
    builder.ComplexType<DiskDto>();

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

ASP.NET Core Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ComputersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ComputerContext context;
    
    public ComputersController(ComputerContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ComputerDto> GetComputers()
    {
        return this.context.Computers.Select(c => new ComputerDto
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Name = c.Name,
            Disks = c.Disks.Select(d => new DiskDto
            {
                Letter = d.Letter,
                Capacity = d.Capacity
            }).ToList()
        });
    }
}
```

This query works but Disks is already expanded because I'm manually creating the list.

```
https://localhost:46324/api/computers?$filter=startswith(name,'t')
```

and output

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:46324/api/$metadata#Collection(ODataPlayground.Dtos.ComputerDto)",
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": 14,
      "Name": "TestComputer1",
      "Disks": [
        {
          "Letter": "C",
          "Capacity": 234.40
        },
        {
          "Letter": "D",
          "Capacity": 1845.30
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 15,
      "Name": "TestComputer2",
      "Disks": [
        {
          "Letter": "C",
          "Capacity": 75.50
        },
        {
          "Letter": "D",
          "Capacity": 499.87
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I then try to expand "Disks" with the following query I get an error:

```
https://localhost:46324/api/computers?$filter=startswith(name,'t')&$expand=disks
```

error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'disks' on type 'ODataPlayground.Dtos.ComputerDto' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
        "details": [],
        "innererror": {
            "message": "Property 'disks' on type 'ODataPlayground.Dtos.ComputerDto' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
            "type": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
            "stacktrace": "...really long stack trace removed for compactness..."
        }
    }
}
```

Question

- I seem to be able to return the top level class as a dto, only exposing the properties a client might need but is it also possible to expose and return a dto as a navigation property?

Non-dto output

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:46324/api/$metadata#Collection(ODataPlayground.Dtos.ComputerDto)",
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": 14,
      "Name": "TestComputer1",
      "Disks": [
        {
          "Id": 16,
          "ComputerId": 14,
          "Letter": "C",
          "Capacity": 234.40
        },
        {
          "Id": 17,
          "ComputerId": 14,
          "Letter": "D",
          "Capacity": 1845.30
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output (with the $filter and $expand query above)

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:46324/api/$metadata#Collection(ODataPlayground.Dtos.ComputerDto)",
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": 14,
      "Name": "TestComputer1",
      "Disks": [
        {
          "Letter": "C",
          "Capacity": 234.40
        },
        {
          "Letter": "D",
          "Capacity": 1845.30
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update #1**

If I add Automapper into the mix and try using the `ProjectTo` method with the following code:

```
    //// Inject context and mapper
    public ComputersController(ComputerContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ComputerDto> GetComputers()
    {
        return this.context.Computers.ProjectTo<ComputerDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
    }
```

I get a different error:

```
    InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type
    'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non - null value of the same type.
    Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.
```

Comment: ```disks != Disks```, it can be the error ?

Comment: Sadly no, `$expand=Disks` does not produce a different result.

Comment: OData does not recognize ComputerDto > Disks as navigation property, because this is a complex type, you need to tell OData that Disks is a relation (expandable) property by using  builder.ComplexType<ComputerDto>().HasMany(c => c.Disks); // this will only works if DiskDto has Id

Comment: @RodrigoGRodrigues Is it not possible to apply the OData query to Computer and then map the result to ComputerDto?

Comment: You might want to look into using a sproc for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I seem to be able to return the top level class as a dto, only exposing the properties a client might need but is it also possible to expose and return a dto as a navigation property?

It's possible, but you need to solve some modelling and implementation specific problems.

First, the modelling. OData only supports collection navigation properties to *entity types*. So in order to map `ComputerDto.Disks` property as navigation property, you need to make `DiskDto` entity type. Which in turn requires it to have a key. So either add `Id` property to it, or associate some other property (for instance, `Letter`) to it:

```cs
//builder.ComplexType<DiskDto>();
builder.EntityType<DiskDto>().HasKey(e => e.Letter);
```

Now the `Disks` property won't be included w/o `$expand` option and also will eliminate the original OData exception.

This was all about OData Edm model and enabling `$expand` options for `Disks`.

The next problem to be solved is related to OData and EF Core query implementation details. Running the filtered query (w/o `$expand`) produces the desired JSON output (no `Disks` included), but the generated EF Core SQL query is

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [d].[Letter], [d].[Capacity], [d].[Id]
FROM [Computers] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Disks] AS [d] ON [c].[Id] = [d].[ComputerId]
WHERE (@__TypedProperty_0 = N'') OR ([c].[Name] IS NOT NULL AND (LEFT([c].[Name], LEN(@__TypedProperty_0)) = @__TypedProperty_0))
ORDER BY [c].[Id], [d].[Id]
```

As you can see, it includes unnecessary joins and columns, which is inefficient.

And with `$expand` options you get the `VisitLambda` exception, which is from EF Core 3.1 query translation pipeline and is caused by the `ToList()` call in the `Disks` member projection, which in turn is needed because the target property type is `ICollection<DiskDto>` and w/o it you get compile time error. It can be solved by making the property type `IEnumerable<DiskDto>` and removing the `ToList()` from projection, which would eliminate the exception, but again will produce the even more inefficient SQL query

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [d].[Letter], [d].[Capacity], [d].[Id], @__TypedProperty_2, [d0].[Letter], [d0].[Capacity], CAST(1 AS bit), [d0].[Id]
FROM [Computers] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Disks] AS [d] ON [c].[Id] = [d].[ComputerId]
LEFT JOIN [Disks] AS [d0] ON [c].[Id] = [d0].[ComputerId]
WHERE (@__TypedProperty_0 = N'') OR ([c].[Name] IS NOT NULL AND (LEFT([c].[Name], LEN(@__TypedProperty_0)) = @__TypedProperty_0))
ORDER BY [c].[Id], [d].[Id], [d0].[Id]
```

All that means is that trying to use OData query directly over EF Core projection query is problematic.

So as a solution for the implementation problems I would suggest [AutoMapper.Extensions.OData](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData) extension which:

> Creates LINQ expressions from `ODataQueryOptions` and executes the query.

What you need is to install the package [AutoMapper.AspNetCore.OData.EFCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.AspNetCore.OData.EFCore/), use AutoMapper configuration similar to this (the essential is to enable null collections and explicit expansion)

```cs
cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
cfg.CreateMap<Computer, ComputerDto>()
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion());
cfg.CreateMap<Disk, DiskDto>()
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion());
```

(note: with this approach the property type can stay `ICollection<DiskDto>`)

and change the controller method similar to this (the essential is to *not* use `EnableQuery`, add options argument and return `IEnumerable` / `ICollection` instead of `IQueryable`)

```cs
using AutoMapper.AspNet.OData;

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<ComputerDto>> GetComputers(
    ODataQueryOptions<ComputerDto> options) =>
    await context.Computers.GetAsync(mapper, options, HandleNullPropagationOption.False);
```

Now both outputs will be as expected, as well as the generated SQL queries:

- (no expand)

output:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/api/$metadata#Collection(ODataTest.Dtos.ComputerDto)",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "TestComputer1"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "TestComputer2"
        }
    ]
}
```

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name]
FROM [Computers] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[Name] IS NOT NULL AND ([c].[Name] LIKE N't%')
```

- with `$expand=disks`

output:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/api/$metadata#Collection(ODataTest.Dtos.ComputerDto)",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "TestComputer1",
            "Disks": [
                {
                    "Letter": "C",
                    "Capacity": 234.4
                },
                {
                    "Letter": "D",
                    "Capacity": 1845.3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "TestComputer2",
            "Disks": [
                {
                    "Letter": "C",
                    "Capacity": 75.5
                },
                {
                    "Letter": "D",
                    "Capacity": 499.87
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [d].[Id], [d].[Capacity], [d].[ComputerId], [d].[Letter]
FROM [Computers] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Disks] AS [d] ON [c].[Id] = [d].[ComputerId]
WHERE [c].[Name] IS NOT NULL AND ([c].[Name] LIKE N't%')
ORDER BY [c].[Id], [d].[Id]
```

Comment: Wow, it's always that one library you miss that does exactly what you want. Your explanation made perfect sense and even helped me learn a bit more about EFCore optimization. Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer.

Comment: Now we just need the OData nuget to update to support .NET 5.